# Traversing two sequences in Freemarker

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, freemarker, templating

I am new to FreeMarker and I am working on a project which uses it.

The scenario is, I have two lists in FreeMarker which I am getting from the backend(say *firstNames* & *lastNames*. Now what I want to do is, I want to loop through these lists and access the values from **both** lists at the **same** index.

I want the output to be something like

```
<#assign firstNames = fNames/>
<#assign lastNames = lNames/>
<body>
    <table>
        <loop from 0 to 5>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello firstNames[i] lastNames[i]</td>
        </tr>
        </loop>
    </table>
</body>
```

For simplicity I will assume that the length of the lists will always be the same(*say 5*).

Is there a way to achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
<#list firstNames as firstName>
  Hello ${firstName} ${lastNames[firstName?index]}
</#list>
```